# Proving the reproducing property of kernel polynomials

Tags: analysis, polynomials, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

I need to prove the following property related to kernel polynomials:

$\int_a^b K_n(t,x)q_n(x)w(x)dx=q_n(t)$,

where $q_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less or equal to $n$, $w(x)$ is a weight function defined over the interval $[a,b]$ and the kernel polynomials are given by,

$K_n(t,x)=\sum_{k=0}^n p_k(t)p_k(x)$. I have seen on class that $\{p_k\}$ is an orthonormal sequence associated to the weight function $w(x)$.

I have no idea how to start, does anyone have a hint on how to begin?

All the help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you mean $q_n(t)$, I have a question though, is $p_k$ an orthonormal basis of your weighted inner product? Please add some context and some tries

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lacks information. I believe $w>0$ is continuous and that $(p_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ forms an orthonormal graduated (i.e. $\deg p_k = k$) basis of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ (which means the orthonormal polynomials for the weight $w$) for the inner product:
$$\langle q,q' \rangle_w = \int_a^b wqq'$$

If so you have the parseval equality (not sure about the name):
$$q(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k(t) \langle q,p_k\rangle_w$$
don't worry this is in fact a finite sum.

If $\deg q \leqslant n$, you get
$$q(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k(t) \langle q,p_k\rangle_w = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k(t) \int_a^b p_k(x) q(x) w(x) dx = \int_a^b \left(\sum_{k=0}^n p_k(t)p_k(x)\right)   q(x) w(x) dx$$
So
$$q(t) =  \int_a^b K_n(t,x) q(x) w(x) dx$$

My advise for next post: please add all the definitions so we don't have to guess and some personal tries.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the tips! (I made sure to add more information). When it comes to (p_k) we have only seen, in class, that it is an orthonormal sequence associated to the weight function w(x). Not that it forms a base for $\mathbb{R} [X]$. How can i conclude that it forms a base?

Comment: This is not very hard, maybe you can show it on your own (it is a good exercise)? You already know that this is a free family since it is orthonormal. You only need to show that it generates $\mathbb{R}[X]$ the main argument is the graduation. I believe it was constructed using Gram-Schmidt? If this is sufficient to you accept the answer so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: Can you just give me a hint how to reach Parseval equality?

Comment: There are a lot of references that do it, again I'm not sure about the name but if you have $x\in E$ a prehilbertian space with orthonormal basis $(e_i)$, $x = \sum \lambda_i e_i$, what can you say about $\lambda_i$, can you express it from $x$ and $e_i$ using the inner product?

Comment: If you can't do that, you should consider reworking on prehilbertian spaces first.